# How would this React code look without React-hooks and with class components rather than functional components?

Tags: reactjs

I just studied React from YouTube lessons, and there all the lessons were built on classes and the usual this.setState, without hooks. How would this React code look without React-hooks and with class components rather than functional components?
The code itself implements an image slider:

React:

```
function Slider({ items }) {
  const [ active, setActive ] = React.useState(0);
  const { length, [active]: slide } = items;

  const next = e => setActive((active + +e.target.dataset.step + length) % length);
  const goTo = e => setActive(+e.target.dataset.index);

    React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => setActive((active + 1 + length) % length), 5000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [active, length]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="slideshow-container">
        <div className="mySlides fade">
          <div className="numbertext">{active + 1} / {length}</div>
          <img src={slide.img} />
          <div className="text">{slide.title}</div>
        </div>
        <a className="prev" onClick={next} data-step={-1}>&#10094;</a>
        <a className="next" onClick={next} data-step={+1}>&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <div className="dots">
        {items.map((n, i) => (
          <span
            key={n.id}
            className={`dot ${i === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
            onClick={goTo}
            data-index={i}
          ></span>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const items = [
  { title: 'One', img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Purity_of_nature.jpg' },
  { title: 'Two', img: 'https://mairie-balma.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Lhers.jpg' },
  { title: 'Three', img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRt-b1iBqHQ_emkm1wFmkM7KQskzIqg7YQPZWW85Sa7k2nNLwgjMw' },
].map((n, i) => ({ ...n, id: i + 1 }));

ReactDOM.render(<Slider items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}


.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


.dots {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.mySlides img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I really recommend you learn hooks. It's actually pretty easy to learn if you've already learned how to manage state with class components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (not fully tested):

```
class Slider {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        active: 0
    }
}
let timeout = null;

componentDidMount() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.setActive(), 5000);
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { active } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.active !=== active {
        if (this.timeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        }
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.setActive(), 5000);
    });
}
componentDidUnmount() {
    if (this.timeout) {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
}

const setActive = (newActive) => {
    const { length } = items;
    this.setState({
        active: (newActive + 1 + length) % length
    });
}


const next = e => {
    const { length } = items;
    this.setActive((this.state.active + +e.target.dataset.step + length) % length);
}
const goTo = e => this.setActive(+e.target.dataset.index);

render() {
    const { length } = items;
    const {active} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="slideshow-container">
                <div className="mySlides fade">
                    <div className="numbertext">{active + 1} / {length}</div>
                    <img src={slide.img} />
                    <div className="text">{slide.title}</div>
                </div>
                <a className="prev" onClick={this.next} data-step={-1}>&#10094;</a>
                <a className="next" onClick={this.next} data-step={+1}>&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <div className="dots">
                {items.map((n, i) => (
                    <span
                        key={n.id}
                        className={`dot ${i === active ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={this.goTo}
                        data-index={i}
                    ></span>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

const items = [
{ title: 'One', img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Purity_of_nature.jpg' },
{ title: 'Two', img: 'https://mairie-balma.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Lhers.jpg' },
{ title: 'Three', img: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRt-b1iBqHQ_emkm1wFmkM7KQskzIqg7YQPZWW85Sa7k2nNLwgjMw' },
].map((n, i) => ({ ...n, id: i + 1 }));

ReactDOM.render(<Slider items={items} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```